# What is wrong with this Coin Change solution using DFS with memoization?

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, memoization

I've solved Leetcode's Coin Change 2 problem with a DFS + memoization approach in Python, with the solution below

```py
# O(m*n)
def change(amount: int, coins: List[int]) -> int:
    cache = {}
    
    def dfs(i, a):
        if a == amount:
            return 1
        
        if a > amount:
            return 0
        
        if i == len(coins):
            return 0
        
        if (i, a) in cache:
            return cache[(i, a)]

        cache[(i, a)] = dfs(i, a + coins[i]) + dfs(i + 1, a)
        
        return cache[(i, a)]
    
    return dfs(0, 0)
```

As a C++ newbie I've been practising my C++ by converting my Leetcode Python solution into a C++ one. This is what I've done:

```
int dfs(int index, int a, int amount, vector<int> coins, vector<vector<int>>& dp) {
    if (a == amount) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a > amount) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (index == coins.size()) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (dp[index][amount] != -1) {
        return dp[index][amount];
    }
    
    dp[index][amount] = dfs(index, a + coins[index], amount, coins, dp) + dfs(index + 1, a, amount, coins, dp);

    return dp[index][amount];
}

int change(int amount, vector<int>& coins) {
    int n = coins.size();
    vector<vector<int>> dp(n,vector<int>(amount+1, -1));
    return dfs(0, 0, amount, coins, dp);
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my C++ solution is not passing all the test cases like my Python solution did. I feel like my lack of knowledge on C++ is making it difficult for me to figure out why my C++ implementation is wrong.

An example of a test case:

```
5
[1,2,5]
```

should return `4`.

Comment: With a small example test case like 5, 1 2 5, you should be able to step through this with a debugger and see where it deviates from the expected.

Comment: @user4581301 I've literally been doing exactly that for an hour, and I literally cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong, which is why I'm here.

Comment: Does `vector<vector<int>> dp(n,vector<int>(amount+1, -1));` create `n` separate vectors or insert the same vector `n` times into `dp`? You could check that by observing in the debugger if changing one vector changes all others, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your memoization in the C++ solution looks at `index` and `amount` (a constant), when your Python one looks at `index` and `a`.

Changing it accordingly fixes it, i.e

```
[...]

    if (dp[index][a] != -1) {
    return dp[index][a];
}

dp[index][a] = dfs(index, a + coins[index], amount, coins, dp) + dfs(index + 1, a, amount, coins, dp);

return dp[index][a];

[...]
```

Comment: I had to add `amount` into my C++ solution, since with the Python solution I didn't have to because of the fact that I can define a function within a function. The inner function knows what amount is. But with C++ I cannot do that hence I had to pass `amount` into my `dfs` function.

Comment: Yes but that's not my point: in your Python solution, the parameters of your memoization are `i` and `a`. In your C++ solution, they're `index` and `amount`. Your Python `i` is your C++ `index`, but your Python `a` isn't your C++ `amount` - it's your C++ `a`. So right now, the function runs once with parameters `0, 0, amount, [...]`, then recursively calls itself with parameters `0, <something different>, amount, [...]` looks into the cache and thinks it has computed that already. Replace all occurences of `[index][amount]` by `[index][a]` and it will work.

Comment: You're absolutely right. This was such a careless mistake of my part. Thank you.